# Privoxy https/socks5 proxy + Authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, https, privoxy

I have bought a paid https proxy to be able to surf the web securely... the proxy needs authentication and I can use it on windows 7 using Proxifier ( www.proxifier.com ) but in Linux there is no Poxifier so I found Privoxy as an alternate but I'm not so familiar with it.
would someone help me set up my proxy please...

I've been searching the web for this but I got confused...

any other suggestions for setting up my proxy on linux is also appreciated :D

Comment: privoxy is a proxy itself. it seems you don't want that, you just want to authenticate to your existing paid proxy, which is anonymous.  I don't know how you'd send more than just http through it but you can set up your web browser specifying the proxy, and it'll prompt once for a user/pass